# sendmail MTA not working with smtp relay - error service unavailable

Tags: ssl, smtp, gmail, sendmail, relay

I've been trying many days to configure sendmail with my G suit custom email address with no success. I've configured everything including TLS, AUTH, App password, and relay settings etc as per google docs.

but still seeing error below shown in /var/log/maillog:

[image: This is maillog file]

Even little help will be a great favor Thanks!

Comment: As root push processing of selected queued messages in verbose mode (It includes transcript of SMTP session).  It usually provides more hints.  `sendmail -v -qR@example.com`  [replace example.com with the recipient domains]

Comment: Can you please assist bit more how Im supposed to debug using this: sendmail -v -qR@example.com Im configuring this for first time